# Combine Regular expression Based on Condition in Java

Tags: java, regex

Following could be accepted formats,

```
(CCC|CC|CCN)/(NNNN-NNNNNNNN)
OR 
(CCC|CC|CCN)/NN/(NN-NNNNN)
```

Where C represents character [A-Z] and N represents Number [0-9]

I manage to create 2 regular expression to match both the conditions,

```
^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z|0-9]{0,1}/\d{4,8}$
OR
^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z|0-9]{0,1}/\d{2}/\d{2,5}$
```

Is it possible to merge them in a single regex based on condition on / (i.e. number of forward slash)?

Sample Valid examples could be :-

```
MAT/1234
XP/1234
XW1/12345678

XU/12/34
KLY/12/34567
RT1/23/45678
```

Comment: Do you have some valid examples to match against ?

Comment: There is an _or_ symbol `|` for regular expressions.

Comment: @brso05: Read the question again. C and N are just notations for Characters and numbers.

Comment: In your question the format of matching is different from the regex you came up with. Please be clear if you are looking for numbers in  format of `1111-11111111` or number with length 4 to 8.

Comment: @brso05: OP is not looking for alteration. _Is it possible to merge them in a single regex based on condition on_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106930/discussion-between-noob-and-brso05).

Comment: see regex in my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** To merge your following two patterns into one:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z|0-9]{0,1}/\d{4,8}$
OR
^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z|0-9]{0,1}/\d{2}/\d{2,5}$
```

You could try:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z|0-9]{0,1}/\d{2}(?:\d{2,6}|/\d{2,5})$
```

[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oU6mV7/5)

Comment: You have used `|` in first part and your regex matches `AA|/1111`. That is incorrect. Removing `|` from it will make it right.

Comment: @noob: You are right. It matches `AA|/1111`.  But OP is not looking for alteration of the original patterns.

Comment: Yea but that's not the way you say OR in character class. It might be confusing to think why did an accepted solution used `|` when there is nothing to OR. Character class itself denotes either of the characters mentioned in it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current format I came up with this regex.

Well not yet sure if OP is looking for format `1111-11111111` or numbers with length of 4 to 8. So I will give solution for both cases which might come in handy to someone in future.

**For format:** `(NNNN-NNNNNNNN)` OR `NN/(NN-NNNNN)`

**Regex:** `^([A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]?)\/((\d{4}-\d{8})|(\d{2}\/\d{2}-\d{5}))$`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ8gO0/2)**</kbd>

---

**For length of numbers in range 4 to 8 and 2 to 5**

**Regex:** `^([A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]?\/)(\d{4,8}|\d{2}\/\d{2,5})$`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zU0gE1/2)**</kbd>

Comment: ^([A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]?\/)(\d{4,8}|\d{2}\/\d{2,5})$ This solution is also works & much simpler. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got little bit longer regex:

```
(?im)^([a-z]{2}[\\da-z]?)/(\\d{4}\\-\\d{8}|\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\-\\d{5})$
```

See demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kX1wZ4/4)

MATCHES:

```
AA2/2222-22222222
AAA/2222-22222222
AA/2222-22222222

AA2/22/22-22222
AA/22/22-22222
AAB/22/22-22222
```

BUT NOT

```
AA2A/2222-22222222A
AAA/2222-222A22222
AA/2222-222222223

2A2/22/22-222222
3AA/22/22-22222
1AB/22/22-22222
```

Comment: You should mention that you are using `i` flag for case insensitivity. It's visible in your example but what if a noob like me copies it directly from here ? :P

Comment: well....if someone like you do that, probably I'll quit :P  anyway  I'm expecting OP knows what's there.

Comment: That's fine. But my question is why deal with case sensitivity here at all ? OP mentioned `[A-Z]` explicitly. It would be a confusion. You can add it as a side note though.

Comment: agreed and 100%. Even after change, I really don't see any difference of hops regex is making to match a string. see https://regex101.com/r/kX1wZ4/5